# write second order difference as a convolution operator

Tags: finite-differences, finite-difference-methods

For $h>0$, let
\begin{equation}
\phi(x)
=
\begin{cases}
h+x,
\quad \text{if} \quad -h\le x\le 0,\\
h-x,
\quad \text{if} \quad \hspace{5mm}0\le x\le h,\\
0,
\quad \hspace{8mm}\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
It is not hard to prove that $(u\ast\phi)''(x)=u(x+h)-2\,u(x)+u(x-h)$, where
    \begin{equation}
 (u\ast\phi)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(z)\,\phi(x-z)\,dz.
 \end{equation}
and $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I am quite curious about the following question. In the study of difference equations, has any reference used the convolution operator with Gaussian-like kernel $\phi(x)$ defined as above to replace the second order difference operator $u(x+h)-2\,u(x)+u(x-h)$? I am not sure about this. Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Since the triangle function can be written as the convolution of a square pulse function with itself, you can also write the above $u\ast \phi$ as the $u$ convolved with the square pulse function twice.